# receive trap with westhawk snmp stack

Tags: java, snmp

I want to recieve snmp trap , I got it on snmp4j , but now I am using westhawk snmp stack library for implementing trap receiver module.I use this library [sample](https://github.com/onebudwazer/my_repo/blob/master/snmp6_1/src/uk/co/westhawk/examplev1/ReceiveTrap.java) for recieving trap ,but this code recieve trap as rawPdu ,and when I edit code recieve nothing , what should I do ?
here's my code :

```
package snmp4j;

import java.util.*;
import uk.co.westhawk.snmp.stack.*;    
import uk.co.westhawk.snmp.event.*;    
import uk.co.westhawk.snmp.util.*;    

public class SnmpTrackTrapReceiver implements TrapListener, Observer
{
    private SnmpContext context;

public void init () 
{

    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 162 ;
    String community = "public" ;
    try 
    {
        context = new SnmpContextv2c(host, port);
        context.setCommunity(community);
        context.addTrapListener(this);
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException exc)
    {
        System.out.println("ReceiveTrap.init(): IOException " 
            + exc.getMessage() + "\n" + exc);
        exc.printStackTrace() ;
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void trapReceived(TrapEvent evt)
{
    int port = evt.getHostPort();
    Pdu trapPdu = evt.getPdu();
    int reqId = trapPdu.getReqId();
    SnmpContextBasisFace rcontext = trapPdu.getContext();
    int version = rcontext.getVersion();
    String host = rcontext.getHost();

    System.out.println("\ttrap id " + reqId 
        + ", v " + SnmpUtilities.getSnmpVersionString(version)
        + " from host " + host
        + ", sent from port " + port);
    System.out.println("\ttrap " + trapPdu.toString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can iterate through trap PDU varbinds using the following code:

```
varbind[] varbinds = trapPdu.getResponseVarbinds();

for (varbind var: varbinds) {
    System.out.println("OID: ", var.getOid().toString());
    System.out.println("Value: ", var.getValue().toString());
}
```

Comment: my problem is code did not recieve any event as trapEvent, you are recieve trap?

Comment: Make sure you have configured contexts for all SNMP versions - v1, v2c, v3. So you can handle all types of incoming trap PDUs.

Comment: I fixed that now, Unfortunately Nothing has changed. what should I do now  ?

Comment: Just debug it. Try setting up a breakpoint within the library code starting from UDP packet receiving point to see what happens.